# WPF EventTrigger not always firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView that I customized visually looking like this:

[image: treeview]

I defined an EventTrigger to react on clicks:

```
<TreeView>            
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenPartListCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PartsTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
                            <Grid Margin="6,4">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Border Name="Bd" 
                                        Background="{Binding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="Black" 
                                        BorderThickness="1.2" 
                                        CornerRadius="0"
                                        MinHeight="35"
                                        Padding="5"     
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                        Margin="{Binding Path=Margin}" >
                                    <Grid>                                            
                                        <Expander Name="Exp" IsExpanded="{TemplateBinding TreeViewItem.IsExpanded}">
                                            <Expander.Header>                                                   
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"                                                                       
                                                                  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=PartsTreeView, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE-80}"  />

                                            </Expander.Header>                                                
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>

                                        <ContentPresenter Name="CntPres"
                                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Visibility="Collapsed"                                                         
                                                    Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=PartsTreeView, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE-80}"  
                                                    />              
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.HasItems" Value="false">
                                    <Setter 
                                          TargetName="Exp" 
                                          Property="Visibility" 
                                          Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter 
                                          TargetName="CntPres" 
                                          Property="Visibility" 
                                          Value="Visible" />            
                                </Trigger>


                                <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.Name" Value="IsSpecial">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFC3AF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.Name" Value="IsNotSpecial">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#8BADC5"/>
                                </Trigger>


                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF0EA"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF0EA"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FFF0EA"/>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate.Resources>                                    
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate.Resources>
                            <StackPanel  IsItemsHost="True"   />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The problem is that clicking on the root element "Ausführungsvorschrift" only expands the tree but the event is not fired. It fires when clicking on sub elements though and it fires when clicking inside the border. But the header does not fire anything.

Comment: yes, it does that. you need to either bind to expand event or to implement a button like behaviour which has the action (obviously in the second you need to programatically tell expander to expand on button click)

Comment: Have you tried previewmousedown?

Comment: @mm8: Yes, I tried. Not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add triggers for the `Expanded` and `Collapsed` events to the `Expander` element in the template:

```
<Expander Name="Exp" IsExpanded="{TemplateBinding TreeViewItem.IsExpanded}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenPartListCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Collapsed">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenPartListCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Expander.Header>
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
    </Expander.Header>
    <ItemsPresenter />
</Expander>
```

Comment: Yes that works. The problem is that I then get `NULL` in `SelectedItem` and I have no idea what was clicked in my ViewModel. Happen to know how to solve this? :-)

Comment: Is PartsTreeView another TreeView or the same one?

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Good one, but I get the last SelectedItem with that. Seems like the SelectedItem gets set after this event fires.

Comment: So you want the root node?

Comment: When I click on a node on the second level then I want that one. When I click a node on the first level then that one. I only have 2 levels. Clicking on the header of the first level only expands. Seems like it does not set the SelectedItem.

Comment: But when you click on the "expander" node, you want to pass this one as the CommandParameter, right?

Comment: Then I get  `PartTreeViewModel` as parameter.

Comment: And what type do you expect?

Comment: A `TreeViewItem`

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"/>` should give the the current TreeViewItem container.